# Playing Video in html / web browser

Tags: javascript, html, video, playback

Is there a way to embed video in html that all browsers support - non html5, doesn't use the `<video>` tag, doesn't depend on flash - may be purely javascript?

Comment: Why would you want that? Care to explain?

Comment: Compatability across all browsers

Comment: no there is not - browsers without HTMLVideo are not worth "supporting"

Comment: I mean don't browsers support video natively without plugins like flash, I need to play a video in a flash and it asks to install flash?

Comment: All browser you should care about support html5 video. You can also use some library like `videojs` to ensure everything works the same across different browsers.

Comment: Don't rely on flash. It will be dead for good in a short time. It's 2017. Trust the `video` tag. See compatibility chart here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=video Use a fallback library like videojs.

Comment: When you say _"I need to play a video in Flash and it asks to install Flash?"_ ...(1) Did you ever test this with Chrome browser? It has Flash built-in so if still says _"install Flash"_ then you fix your problem HTML code by using `embed` tag to add the SWF file (Flash app)... (2) What format is your video? If MP4, then just load same video using `video` tag. The video tag is HTML5 code. PS: If a browser used in 2017 doesn't process HTML5 code (everywhere since 2010) then leave it behind.

Comment: "I need to play a video in Flash and it asks to install Flash?" That was a typo it should be "I need to play a video in a web page and it asks to install Flash?"  Chrome works fine except the other browsers. MP4. It's not about my browser but other users'

Answer (score 3):

Playback of video isn't just browsers supporting the `<video>` tag. Browsers should also have support for the codec, audio/video-container format (eg; MPEG) and possibly DRM. The previous suggestion (install Quicktime, VLC, even using Flash or MS Silverlight) take away this support by using some 3rd party component that runs outside of the browser, but still require a user to install and configure those components. Since those components are usually platform specific you would not really gain any extra browser-support, just a lot of complaints. You can forget about supporting mobile and tablet altogether.

Nowadays almost all platforms and browsers and  have decent support for `<video>` and/or `<audio>` tags and codecs, container-formats and DRM. There are some nice libraries that take care of abstracting playback, DRM, the GUI and analytics and some of them have fallback to Flash. 
Suggestions from Muthu Kumaran; videoJS and MediaElement.js, both open source, do take some work to get up & running. Other alternatives are

- **BitMovin**, commercial. Pretty large, feature rich and expensive.
- **JWPlayer**, open source and partially commercial. Comes from a Flash-background. Has very large userbase and has been around for ages.
- **TheoPlayer**, commercial. Solid player, has been around for a while.
- **MeisterPlayer**, opensource and partially commercial, new kid on the block. Looks promising with a few very large customers.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to play video without `<video>` tag or flash. But you need to install specific software to play video in browser like

**Apple QuickTIme**

You can use HTML to communicate with the QuickTime browser plug-in or ActiveX control when displaying QuickTime-compatible content in a browser.
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/QuickTime/Conceptual/QTScripting_HTML/QTScripting_HTML_Document/ScriptingHTML.html

**VLC Web Plugin**

The VLC media player webplugins are native browser plugins, similar to Flash or Silverlight plugins and allow playback inside the browser of all the videos that VLC media player can read.
https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:WebPlugin/

I wouldn't recommend any of these. You should simply use `<video>` tag to play video. There are many video library which has fallback support for older browsers like,

- Video.js - http://videojs.com/ (dependency required for older browser https://github.com/videojs/videojs-flash)
- MediaElement.js - http://www.mediaelementjs.com/

Comment: But <video> tag didn't work in old versions of Firefox, Opera

Comment: Updated my answer... set two last lines

Comment: @bodesam what old version of Firefox you got? VideoJS and MediaElement all rely on `<video>` tag or Flash plugin to decode a/v data.

Answer (score 0):

**Cross-Browser HTML Video Code**

Below is a sample of HTML you can use for video playback that supports the HTML5 `video` tag in *modern* browsers, but with nice video "fallback" code for older HTML4 browsers created the past 20 years.

```
<figure aria-labelledby="videocaption3">
    <!-- VIDEO: The HTML5 'video' element is the primary source of the various video fallback elements below. Older browsers like IE 5-8 (using ActiveX) that do not recognize the 'video' HTML5 element will try and load the 'object' element version instead. -->
    <video 
        id="video3" 
        controls="controls" 
        preload="metadata" 
        style="width:320px;height:180px;border:none;outline:none;" 
        title="My Video" 
        aria-label="My Video">
        <!-- SOURCE: In this old ActiveX version, Microsoft Windows in Internet Explorer used the object ActiveX form while all other browsers used the 'embed' element below as fallback. -->
        <source src="video3.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        <source src="video3.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
        <!-- OBJECT: In this old ActiveX version, Microsoft Windows in Internet Explorer used the object ActiveX form while all other browsers used the 'embed' element below as fallback. -->
        <object 
            id="object3" 
            name="object3" 
            data="video3.wmv" 
            type="video/x-ms-wmv" 
            style="width: 320px;height: 180px;border: none;outline: none;" 
            title="My Video" 
            aria-label="My Video">
                <!-- EMBED: In this old version, non-Internet Explorer, older, non-HTML5 browsers would recognize this fallback 'embed' version element and call their plugins and players to display the file below. Additional fallback in the form of a 'noembed' element with alert text would trigger for those user agents that do not support multimedia or the embed tag (as it was never part of an official HTML release). I recommend you use this old syntax if you are supporting older browsers that do not understand the newer HTML5 elements. -->
                <embed 
                       id="embed3" 
                       src="video3.wmv" 
                       type="video/x-ms-wmv" 
                       style="width: 320px;height: 180px;border: none;outline: none;" 
                       title="My Video" 
                       aria-label="My Video">
                    <noembed>-->
                    <!-- FALLBACK TEXT ALERT: If the user agent does not support video, give them a simple text alert below. -->
                    Sorry, your browser does not support this video.
                    </noembed>
                </embed>
        </object>
    </video>
    <!-- CAPTION: Captions wrap around the video elements the same as img, picture, and audio elements. -->
    <figcaption id="videocaption3"><small>"My Video"</small></figcaption>
</figure>
```

Most browsers today will play video natively using the new HTML5 element. No plugin or player needed. If the browser doesn't support the "video" element, it falls back down to `object` (old IE), then `embed` (Netscape and non-IE) elements and will require a player be installed. Keep in mind this doesn't address the problem of what browser or version your user is using, operating system, movie encoding types supported, and what player types or versions they have installed (or not installed). There are too many variables that can shut down playback in older browsers. In addition, if your users do have a video player installed, each one may or may not support the video encoding types or version you offer, or on their specific OS or device.

I would start with supplying MPEG4 movies (widest support) first in the `video` element and encode other types. Add them to the code below to widen the chances you support all the operating systems, codecs, players, plugins, and browser versions out there.